# Apache Beam Python SDK support for BigQuery Storage API

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Currently Python SDK does not support  BigQuery Storage API.

We need some features of this API in our pipeline, specifically:

- Committed mode (records are available for read immediately after they are written)
- Exactly-once delivery semantics (no duplicated records)

Both of these features are not available in WriteToBigQuery PTransform.

Instead of waiting for official implementation, I am thinking about a simple workaround: custom DoFn that creates BQ Storage API Client in its **setup** method and then simply commits record to BQ in the **process** method. Records can be batched or grouped in a single commit.

Such naive approach looks like a pretty straightforward thing to do, however I am thinking what the Cons of it would be.
One thing that comes to mind, is that such DoFn would become a bottleneck of a pipeline and could make scaling of it a very difficult task for the runner.

Is my thinking correct?
Any other considerations?

Comment: Hi Corveen, I am also interested in these question, do you have any update on it?

Comment: yeah I'm interested as well

Answer (score 0):

Hey so after poking around the docs, It looks like the bigquery storage api is now supported

checkout the parameter `method`, looks like one can say `DIRECT_READ` and use it that way

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.48.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html?highlight=bigquerysource#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.ReadFromBigQuery

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35577362)

Comment: Gotcha, will do